# dtruss not working on Mojave

Tags: terminal, xcode, dtrace

Running `dtruss` on 10.14.4 (Xcode 10.2) gives me this:

```
tmp$ sudo dtruss ./ls
dtrace: failed to enable '
 #pragma D option quiet

 ': Failed to enable probe
CSCppMachTaskContainer pid_for_task failed for task 20003, err 5CSCppMachTaskContainer...
```

This is not a code signing issue (I resigned that `ls` I'm running). I also already disabled System Integrity Protection so it's not that either. Did anyone see this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have learned today that dtrace isn't really supported any more:

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17853312

I'm leaving this out in case someone runs into this.